# Upgrading Python 3.7 to 3.9 on macOS Big Sur

Tags: python

I'm trying to upgrade Python 3.7 to 3.9 on macOS Big Sur. I'm also trying to avoid losing packages that were installed on Python 3.7 and reinstalling them again on Python 3.9

I tried using

```
brew install python3
brew update && brew upgrade python
```

which yielded

```
Already up-to-date.
Warning: python3 3.9.1_7 already installed
```

However when I run `python3 --version` it yields `Python 3.7.0`

Is this an issue with the alias? Is there a way to uninstall Python 3.7 and keep Python 3.9?

Running `brew link python3` yields

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python@3.9

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python@3.9
```

Comment: Sounds like your `PATH` is wrong. What's the output from `type -a python3`? What does your `PATH` look like, and are you manipulating it from your shell's startup files? Please [edit] to provide these details.

Comment: There is no way really to have all your installed packages travel with you. The architecture of `pip` requires you to install the packages you want into the Python version you want them for. You can run `pip freeze` in the old Python and then (probably manually prune the list and) `pip install` the same packages into the new version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this frustrating error by first removing the Python 3.7 manually, by deleting it from the `Applications` folder and then uninstalling Python 3.9 using `brew uninstall python3`

Next, I downloaded and installed the latest Python from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) and it worked!

To save all the installed packages by generating a requirements file, Run

```
python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and to install them in another environment, Run

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use official binaries:

1. Download version you need from the [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Call the `.pkg`
3. Invoke `Update Shell Profile.command` script under `/Applications/Python\ 3.XX/`
4. After all reboot your terminal
5. Check your Python version. The old version and dependencies remain intact.
   [image]