# How to either downgrade or remove Python 3.9 on macOS

Tags: python, macos

I'm using macOS and need to downgrade my Python 3.9 (not conda) to 3.7.7, for which purpose I wanted to remove the version from Library/Frameworks like the former ones but didn't find there.
Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MacOS?

Comment: @Luke Yes, I am

Comment: You can try referring to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004178/upgrading-python-3-7-to-3-9-on-macos-big-sur/66005134#66005134)

Answer (score 0):

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python
```