# How to get rid of multiple versions of python and get a newer one?

Tags: python, macos, installation, homebrew

I want to update my python to the 3.8 version at least. However, it looks like I have multiple different versions of pythno3 in my Mac (Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7). When I install the newer version, looks like it doesn't overwrite the past versions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004178/upgrading-python-3-7-to-3-9-on-macos-big-sur), the advise was to remove python3.7 from the Application folder and install the newer version from the python website. I did that, but it didn't work and now I have this

```
python --version
```

> Python 3.7.4

```
type -a python3
```

> python3 is
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
> python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
> python3 is /usr/bin/python3

How do I remove all the 3.7 versions that I have and get the 3.8 or 3.9 one?

Comment: Because I wanna avoid a downvote I deleted my answer. https://python.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-mac

Comment: https://osxuninstaller.com/uninstall-guides/properly-uninstall-python-mac/

Comment: I left you the reference

Comment: thank you. I used those steps before, e.g. removing the python3.7 from the application folder. Following the recommendations from the link you gave me, I tried to use sudo rm -rf command on all the paths I got from type -a python3. However, for this one /usr/bin/python3 I have no permission even though I typed my password. So I still have python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Install Homebrew - https://brew.sh/

Then run "brew install python@3.9" in your terminal

Comment: Yulia cant remove the old version of python, Yulia wants to remove any old version and then install the newer

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but i think brew will do that for you. Or it should at least override them with the latest version.